# Read file names from a directory

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-io

I was wondering if there's an easy way in C++ to read a number of file names from a folder containing many files. They are all bitmaps if anyone is wondering.

I don't know much about Windows programming so I was hoping it can be done using simple C++ methods.

Comment: See also [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Boost provides a [`basic_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator) which provides a C++ standard conforming input iterator which accesses the contents of a directory.  If you can use Boost, then this is at least cross-platform code.

Answer (score 19):

C++17 includes a **standard** way of achieve that

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file2.txt");
    for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

Possible output:

```
sandbox/a
sandbox/file1.txt
sandbox/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

Since you specify Windows,

I think you're looking for [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) and [`FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Note bene: those functions are part of the Microsoft API, not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 9):

Just had a quick look in my snippets directory. Found this. This uses Microsoft's Win32 API directly:

```
vector<CStdString> filenames;
CStdString directoryPath("C:\\foo\\bar\\baz\\*");

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData; 
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(directoryPath, &FindFileData);

if (hFind  != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
              filenames.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

This gives you a vector with all filenames in a directory. It only works on Windows of course.

---

[João Augusto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6909/jo%c3%a3o-augusto) noted in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/609909/15168):

*Don't forget to check after `FindClose(hFind)` for:*

```
DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
{
  // Error happened        
}
```

*It's especially important if scanning on a network.*

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the POSIX opendir() and readdir() functions.  See [this manual page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) which also has some great example code.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are programming for Windows I recommend you to use the native Win32 `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` functions.   These give you full control over how you search for files. These are simple C APIs and are not hard to use.

Another advantage is that Win32 errors are not hidden or made harder to get at due to the C/C++ library layer.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is -

1. `system("dir | findstr \".bmp\" > temp.txt ");`
2. Now read temp.txt line by line to get all filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `glob()`?

```
glob_t glob_result;
glob("/foo/bar/*",GLOB_TILDE,NULL,&glob_result);
for(unsigned int i=0;i<glob_result.gl_pathc;++i){
  cout << glob_result.gl_pathv[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check that glob() returns zero, as well as freeing the allocated glob_result with globfree().