# Find words in files c++

Tags: c++, find, filestream

I want to find a certain word by searching all files in a folder, example below find a certain word by searching all files in a folder, example below...

I have a path to file1, file2 and file3

In file1 contains word "Apple"
In file2 contains word "Orange"
In file3 contains word "Banana"

[image: Here is the screenshot]

I want my program to say the file that contains the word "Banana"
Anyone know?, My Code is in C++

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Let's see what you have so far and tell us specifically what is happening.

Comment: Lots of options exist.  You could aim for reading the file into a string and then going for string::find or using the isteam::get with delimiter to hunt the first character down before checking the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++17, the filesystem library has been introduced. This makes live easier.

Now, we have an iterator, that iterates over all files in a directory using the [directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator). There is even a version available, that will iterate over all sub-directories.

So, then we will use this iterator to copy all directory entries into a `std::vector`. Please note: the `std::vector` has a so called [range constructor (5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). You give it a begin and an end iterator and it fills the `std::vector` with all values given by the iterator. So, the line:

```
std::vector fileList(fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {});
```

will read all directory entries into the vector. The {} will be used as the default constructor, which is equal to the [end iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/directory_iterator).

So, now we have all filenames. We will open all regular files in a loop and read the file completely into the memory. Note: For big files this may cause trouble!

Similar to the `std::vector`, also the `std::string` has a range constructor. And as iterator we will use the `istreambuf` iterator. With that we will read all charachtes from the opened file. So, after

```
std::string fileContent(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream), {});
```

the complete contents of the file will be in the `std::string` variable "fileContent".

Then, we loop over the `std::vector` with all lookup strings, and search the loop string in the "fileContent" string using `std::search`.

If we could find the lookup string, then we show the filename and the lookup string on the screen.

By using modern C++ language elements and libraries, we can do the whole task with just a few lines of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// Namespace alias for easier writing
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

// Some demo test path with files
const fs::path startPath{ "c:\\temp\\" };

// Some test strings that we are looking for
std::vector<std::string> lookUpStrings{ "Apple","Banana","Orange" };

int main() {

    // Get all file names of the files in the specified directory into this vector
    std::vector fileList(fs::directory_iterator(startPath), {});

    // In a loop, open all files an search for lookup strings
    for (const fs::directory_entry& de : fileList) {

        // Open file and check, if it could be opened
        if (fs::is_regular_file(de.path()))
        if (std::ifstream fileStream{ de.path().string() }; fileStream) {

            // Read complete file
            std::string fileContent(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream), {});

            // Search for the lookup strings
            for (const std::string& l : lookUpStrings)
                if (std::search(fileContent.begin(), fileContent.end(), l.begin(), l.end()) != fileContent.end())
                    std::cout << "File '" << de.path().string() << "' contains '" << l << "'\n";
        }
        else std::cerr << "\*** Error: Could not open file '" << de.path().string() << "'\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked!! THX! S2

Answer (score 2):

For each file in the directory you can create an "input file stream" with:

```
std::ifstream myStream(filename);
```

where filename must match the name of a file in the folder obviously, and then you initialize an empty string with:

```
std::string line;
```

this string will hold the lines of the file when you read them in. Now you create a while loop that keeps reading in lines from the file until there are no more. If it finds a line containing the word "Banana", you output the filename:

```
while(getline(myStream, line))
{
    if (line.find("Banana") != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "Banana was found in: " << filename << std::endl;
}
```

Do this for every file in the directory, you need to write a loop that goes through the files in the directory.

Comment: I believe the OP's question is more about iterating through a directory.

Comment: If that is the case, then this question has already been asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609203/read-file-names-from-a-directory/609236#609236

Comment: How can such a flat wrong answer ("getline(myStream, filename") get 2 upvotes?

Comment: @ArminMontigny No idea, thanks for pointing it out though, corrected the mistake.